# internal 500 error occur on server..how to remove it

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I'm uploading my new site which is built using codeigniter.
But its giving  internal 500 server error.
I don't know, how to enable re-write module on server by htaccess code, how to enable apache mode_rewrite      on server by htaccess code?

```
    php_value upload_max_filesize 20M  
    php_value post_max_size 20M      
    php_value max_execution_time 90
    php_value max_input_time 300 

    # Make sure directory listing is disabled
    Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
    # disable the Apache MultiViews directive if it is enabled on the server. It plays havoc with URL rewriting
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine on


    # NOTICE: If you get a 404 play with combinations of the following commented out lines
    #AllowOverride All
    #RewriteBase /wherever/pyro/is

    # Restrict your site to only one domain
    # !important USE ONLY ONE OPTION


    # Option 1: To rewrite "www.domain.com -> domain.com" uncomment the following lines.
    #RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]


    # Option 2: To rewrite "domain.com -> www.domain.com" uncomment the following lines.
    #RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..+$ [NC]
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.+)$ [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]


    # Keep people out of codeigniter directory and Git/Mercurial data
    RedirectMatch 403 ^/(system\/cms\/cache|system\/codeigniter|\.git|\.hg).*$

    # Send request via index.php (again, not if its a real file or folder)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d


    <IfModule mod_php5.c>
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule !mod_php5.c>
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>

</ IfModule>
```

Comment: HTTP 500 error debugging should always start in your web servers error log. It might be totally unrelated to the rewrite rules.

Comment: Read you Apache error.log and tell us what the actual error you see there.

Answer (score 1):

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_php5.c>
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

</ IfModule>
```

In the last line, why did you add an extra

```
</ IfModule>
```

Just remove the last line, and everything is working just fine!

Comment: Just remove </ IfModule> Everything working just fine! (Tested)